# Know Previous Acitivity of My App

Tags: android

I have my main menu which have button: A and B

Both buttons can launch activity C.

However if, activity C is launched from activity A, it will perform a specific action,
if it is launched from activity B it will reacted otherwise.

Is there a way to find the name of the previous activity in android ? 
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both A and B, simply pass an extra in the intent that's used to launch C.

For example, from A:

```
Intent launch_from_a = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
launch_from_a.putExtra("from", "ActivityA");
```

And from B:

```
Intent launch_from_b = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
launch_from_b.putExtra("from", "ActivityB");
```

And in C:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
if ("ActivityA".equals(from)) {
}
else if ("ActivityB".equals(from)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approch is to declare a member like `static String act = "a"` in activity A (smewhere in oncreate()) and overwrite it's value in activity B `A.act = "b"` (also in oncreate(). In activity C you test it's value.